# Specify severity error for tslint rule import-blacklist

Tags: tslint

How do I specify severity = error for rule import-blacklist of tslint (i.e red squiggly line) ?
I'd like to disallow import that starts with "packages".
I know tslint is going to be obsolete soon but for now we still use tslint.

I tried the following:

```
"import-blacklist": [
    true,
    [
        "^packages.*$"
    ],
    {
        "severity": [
            "error"
        ]
    }
]
```

But it still show yellow squiggly line as warning.

If i use an object as config like:

```
"import-blacklist": {
    "severity": "error",
    "options": [
         // what should i put here ?
    ]
}
```

Where should I put the pattern to ?

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled upon this. So this is what I found working

```
 "import-blacklist": {
     "options": ["true", ["@material-ui/core$"]],
     "severity": "error"
  }
```